# Is there a downside to deleting Previous Versions of Sharepoint 2010 List workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have many workflows with (Previous Version: 1/1/2015... ) etc.

Is there a downside to deleting these previous versions? 
I read this post by Nik Patel: [link](http://nikpatel.net/page/17/) where he says:

*You can’t manage (or delete) work flow status columns from the list settings page, site columns gallery, or site content type gallery.*

However I don't seem to find these columns in lists which have many previous versions of workflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these multiple columns only occure, when you rename your workflow during versions.

The only downside that comes to my mind is that you will loose your running workflows in that versions (if you have any).

Comment: To add to this, one thing I make sure of before deleting the previous versions of a workflow is make sure there are no running instances, other than that you should be okay to delete.